# Opening a link in a new tab leaves it's focus state active

Tags: html, css, anchor

#### Problem

I have an anchor tag which has the following styles:

```
a {
  color: #E91E63;

  &:focus,
  &:hover {
    color: #2196F3;
  }
}
```

When I open this link using right click and select **Open link in new tab**, the link maintains the focused state color. I would prefer if the link didn't remain focused and went back to the default color `#E91E63`.

I could just set the focus style to be `#E91E63`, but I want mobile devices to be `#2196F3` when a user taps the link.

#### Demo

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/todkLvfp/

#### Question

Is there anyway to remove this focus state or reset the color without using JS?

Comment: short answer: no. you can't do it without js.

Comment: As I understand it, are you just trying to make the colour change only when hovered? If so, why do you need a focus?

Comment: @Amy I need the `:focus` so there is a colour change on mobile devices.

Answer (score 2):

```
a {  
  &:link,          
  &:visited {   
    color: #E91E63;  
   }  
  &:hover {
    color: #2196F3;
   }
}
```

Use this style. The color will reset back to normal after opening the link in a new tab.

Comment: This won't solve the issue as I still need the `:focus` declaration for mobile devices (https://jsfiddle.net/todkLvfp/4/) :/ thanks though.

Comment: What should be the color on focus?

Comment: The color should be #2196F3 on focus

Answer (score 0):

You should use `:active` instead of `:focus`. An anchor tag is active while it is being clicked on, but it returns to its original state when the mouse button is released.

```
a, a:visited {
  color: #E91E63;
}

a:hover, a:active {
  color: #2196F3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is in using `:not` with `!important`

```
a {
  &:not(:hover),
  &:not(:focus) {
    color: #E91E63 !important;
  }

  &:focus,
  &:hover {
    color: #2196F3;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure JS is necessary. The above solution (active instead of focus) is good except for the users who TAB through your webpage and want to experience a change in focus. BTW- page refresh is another scenario where a focused element remains in effect. I had this with button-like elements that had identical focus/active/hover effects and I noticed that the focused button remained after I refreshed the page, which brought me back to a "home state." Not only was the focused element misleading (not the home button), but I got a 2nd highlight effect over any other button I hovered over, that is until I clicked something which brought things back in sync.

Comment: it's not answer.